# Software & Updates application won't launch after upgrade to 19.04

Tags: software-center, 19.04

When I click on the "Software & Updates" app icon nothing happens, when I try to run "/usr/bin/software-properties-gtk", I get the following error:

```
ERROR:dbus.proxies:Introspect error on :1.961:/: dbus.exceptions.DBusException: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.NoReply: Message recipient disconnected from message bus without replying
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/software-properties-gtk", line 100, in <module>
    app = SoftwarePropertiesGtk(datadir=options.data_dir, options=options, file=file)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/gtk/SoftwarePropertiesGtk.py", line 172, in __init__
    self.backend.Reload();
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/dbus/proxies.py", line 70, in __call__
    return self._proxy_method(*args, **keywords)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/dbus/proxies.py", line 145, in __call__
    **keywords)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/dbus/connection.py", line 651, in call_blocking
    message, timeout)
dbus.exceptions.DBusException: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name :1.961 was not provided by any .service files
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

requests_unixsocket was the problem, and it required idna, which I did not have, solution was `sudo pip3 install idna`

Comment: Well solved on your own. Do not hesitate to accept your own answer.